# Errors in project objective c - Beginner niveau

Tags: objective-c

first of all im new to this forum.

I am working on a practise project for school and I a have some errors in this project which I just can't seem to solve.
It's about a project for a game were you can us circle and cross and when one has 3 crosses or circles that player wins.
It's not the intention to make it work like a real game with graphics, Just the UML Class diagram.
But Now I have problems with decompiling it without errors.
It has bugs in there which I can't solve, and I need you guys help for this.

The errors are as follows:

```
Vak.h: Type name requires a specifier or qualifier
Vak.h: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
Vak.h: Expected ';' at end of declaration list
Vak.h: Type name requires a specifier or qualifier
Vak.h: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
Vak.h: Expected ';' at end of declaration list
Vak.h: Class 'Vak' defined without specifying a base class

vak.m: Expected method body
vak.m: Expected method body
```

here is the code and its in seperated files.

```
#ifndef Vak_h    
#define Vak_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface  Vak
{
  -(void) setisGevuld(Speelstuk);
  -(void) getisGevuld(Speelstuk);
}
@end

#endif


#import "Vak.h"

@implementation Vak
Boolean isGevuld;

-(void) setisGevuld(Speelstuk)
{

}

-(void) getisGevuld(Speelstuk)
{

}
@end
```

and that's the code for this project that gives me errors.
I hope people can help me fix the errors I said before.

Answer (score 0):

You declared you method wrong, if you wanted method without any parama it goes like this

```
-(void) setisGevuld;
```

Or with param

```
-(void) setisGevuld:(Speelstuk) param1;
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, please remove define preprocessor in your header file, you will not need it here. #define defines a macro which is replaced even before compilation starts. Then please define properly your method.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface  Vak
{
  -(void) setisGevuld:(Speelstuk*) namedObj
  -(void) getisGevuld:(Speelstuk*) namedObj
}
@end

#import "Vak.h"

@implementation Vak
Boolean isGevuld;

-(void) setisGevuld:(Speelstuk*) namedObj
{

}

-(void) getisGevuld:(Speelstuk*) namedObj
{

}
@end
```

Comment: This might fix the errors but it's not right at all. 1) `isGevuld` is declared as a global variable (not an instance variable). 2) The parameter types should probably be `Boolean`, not `Speelstuck *` (whatever that is). 3) Why would the "get" method take a parameter and not return anything? 4) Why not simply use a property instead of doing it the hard way?

Comment: im sorry I still have trouble getting it fixed I fixed some errors but not all.